# Which one should I choose in the Apple Content Rights section?

Tags: app-store-connect

I bought SVGs from Flaticon and used them in my app. I have SVGs licenses. In this case, which one should I choose in the Apple Content Rights section when publishing my app?

[image]

Comment: So according to your description, your app includes third-party content and you have the necessary rights…

Comment: @DarkDust But it is a product that I bought as a result. It's my product. Would it still be a third-party product?

Comment: What "product"? It's about _content_. You have third-party SVGs (content) that you include in your app, don't you? And you are allowed to ship the third-party SVGs because you have acquired the necessary license, don't you? It's not "your" content in the sense that you are not the creator/copyright owner, the rights are with someone else (a third party), yet you can confirm that you have necessary permission to include it.